# Enforce foreign key constraints in GORM SQLite

Tags: sqlite, go, foreign-keys, go-gorm

Answer: Use `db.Exec("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")` to enforce foreign key constraint checks. Thanks @outdead

When I update my SQLite database using GORM, foreign key constraints aren't enforced.

I have these 2 models:

```
type Cat struct {
    ID      int   
    Name    string
    Breed   string
    OwnerID int  
    Owner   Owner 
}

type Owner struct {
    ID    int   
    Name  string
    Phone string
}
```

Which correctly creates a foreign key constraint where `owner_id` references `id` in `owners`. This can be verified by running: `.schema cats` in the SQLite shell:

```
CREATE TABLE `cats` (`id` integer,`name` text,`breed` text,`owner_id` integer,PRIMARY KEY (`id`),CONSTRAINT `fk_cats_owner` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `owners`(`id`));
```

I have tried `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` which enforces foreign keys when I run commands in the SQLite shell. If I try to update an `owner_id` to an `id` that doesn't exist in `owners`, I get: `Error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`, which is the behaviour that I want, however, GORM is still able to execute these updates without receiving this error.

Comment: Every new connection to a sqlite database needs to explicitly turn on foreign key enforcement for that connection. It's not a one and done thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to exec query to turn on `PRAGMA foreign_keys` before updating

```golang
if res := db.Exec("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON", nil); res.Error != nil {
    return res.Error
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much. It was the `db.Exec("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON", nil)` that fixed the issue for me. The `gorm` struct tags are not required as the foreign key constraints are created by Gorm by simply referencing `Owner` as type `Owner`

Comment: Yes, you're right, you don't need to define a tag, you use a simple linkage. My fault.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the other answer is to append `?_foreign_keys=on` to the connection string:

```
db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("my.db?_foreign_keys=on"), &gorm.Config{})
```

See the [go-sqlite3 driver](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3#connection-string) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64598510/67022).

Verified working with gorm v1.23.1, gorm's sqlite driver v1.3.1, and go-sqlite3 v2.0.3.